# Image bleeding through absolute positioned element when parent has border radius

Tags: html, css, image, rendering

I have a parent div with a border radius set to overflow: hidden. The image beneath respects the radius somewhat. When I add an absolutely positioned element on top, the image bleeds through at the border. I've tried wrapping the image in another div but it didn't help.

[image: bleeding image]

jsbin is here
[bin](https://jsbin.com/yoguvaz/edit?html,css,output)

```
*{


 box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
}
.parent{
  border-radius: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
}

img{
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.absolute{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80px;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: What browser is this on? I'm not seeing this on Chrome 105.0.5195.102 or firefox 104.0.2

Comment: To further the above, weirdly I *am* seeing this in both Chrome 105.0.5195.102 and 105.0.5195.127 (the latest stable build).

Comment: Bizarre.  I just looked at it on my phone and under certain zoom levels I see it but others I don't. I can also see the horizontal line faintly too. Thank you for introducing me to placekitten.com think ill be using that resource myself on projects

Comment: I do see it on Chrome - but it comes and goes as I zoom in and out. It's screen pixels 'left behind' when the system has to map CSS pixel (or part thereof) to the several pixels that make up one CSS pixel nowadays.